# Floating help and confusion

Tags: html, css, css-float

My problem is fairly simple but has me really stumped.

[image]

(The RHS pic is the problem!)

I have a thumbnail with the following css:

```
float: none;
margin-right: 0;
display: block;
```

and to the right of that I have some text with the following css:

```
position: relative;
text-decoration: none;
text-indent: 0;
```

---

Now this works great! However, when the user resizes the window the text jumps below the thumbnail which I don't want (I'm using a responsive website)! How can I prevent this happening the text behaving like this?
I have been playing around with it for ages and can't solve this problem:(.

Comment: Any chance of seeing the HTML and all the relevant CSS? A minimal demo on jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com would be nice.

Comment: simply put your thumbnail in a container div and define your width and a large height and float it left, then float your text left.

Answer (score 1):

You can add float left attribute to your image and span text, and add to a margin left to your text

```
.box {
    width: 210px; 
    vertical-align: text-top;
    display: table-cel
}
.box img {
    float: left;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 100px;
}
.box span.text {
    float: left;
    width: 100px;   
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Can you view an example in jsfiddle: [here](http://jsfiddle.net/q7B6a/)

Comment: I think this is the best answer. Both elements should float as they shouldn't interfere with each other.

Answer (score 0):

```
 As per my understanding, the reason might be: 
There may be some float left given to the thumbnail image somewhere
```

inside the style written for lower screen sizes. The best 
thing you can do is, inspect using firebug or something and check 
whether any float left is given to the thumbnail image. If so, remove that, or give it as 
float as none.

If you are ok with having the entire text below the image when the screen is resized, you can make use of clear: both for lower screen size, which has to be given the text div.

If you could give a link to review, it will be easy to tackle the real problem. Hope my solution helps. Thank you :-)

Answer (score 0):

This appears to do what you want:

```
<html>
    <head>     
        <style> 
        img {
            float: left;
            width: 40px;
            height: 40px;
            border: 1px solid gold;
            margin-left: 5px;
        }
        .text {
            margin-left: 50px;
        }
        .container {
            width: 150px;
            border-left: 3px solid red;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
        <img>
        <div class="text">This should stay aligned and not go under the thumbnail.</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```